# Polars SQL Context filter by date or datetime

Tags: python, python-polars, rust-polars

I'm trying to write a query against parquet using Polars SQL Context.  It's working great if I pre-filter my arrow table by date.  I cannot figure out how to use date in the SQL query.

works:

```
filters = define_filters(event.get("filters", None))
table = pq.read_table(
    f"s3://my_s3_path{partition_path}",
    partitioning="hive",
    filters=filters,
)
df = pl.from_arrow(table)
ctx = pl.SQLContext(stuff=df)
sql = "SELECT things FROM stuff"
new_df = ctx.execute(sql,eager=True)
```

doesn't work (`filters==None` in this case):

```
filters = define_filters(event.get("filters", None))
table = pq.read_table(
    f"s3://my_s3_path{partition_path}",
    partitioning="hive",
    filters=filters,
)
df = pl.from_arrow(table)
ctx = pl.SQLContext(stuff=df)
sql = """
    SELECT things 
    FROM stuff 
    where START_DATE_KEY >= '2023-06-01' and START_DATE_KEY < '2023-06-17'
"""
new_df = ctx.execute(sql,eager=True)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xaras/projects/arrow-lambda/loose.py", line 320, in <module>
    test_runner(target=args.t, limit=args.limit, is_debug=args.debug)
  File "/Users/xaras/projects/arrow-lambda/loose.py", line 294, in test_runner
    rows, metadata = test_handler(target, limit, display=True, is_debug=is_debug)
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xaras/projects/arrow-lambda/loose.py", line 110, in test_handler
    response = json.loads(handler(event, None))
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xaras/projects/arrow-lambda/serverless/app.py", line 42, in handler
    new_df = ctx.execute(
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xaras/.pyenv/versions/pyarrow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/sql/context.py", line 275, in execute
    return res.collect() if (eager or self._eager_execution) else res
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xaras/.pyenv/versions/pyarrow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/utils/deprecation.py", line 95, in wrapper
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/xaras/.pyenv/versions/pyarrow/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/lazyframe/frame.py", line 1713, in collect
    return wrap_df(ldf.collect())
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
exceptions.ComputeError: cannot compare 'date/datetime/time' to a string value (create native python { 'date', 'datetime', 'time' } or compare to a temporal column)
```

UPDATE for addl info:

I started using `cast('2023-06-01' as date)`.  This runs, but does not return any records.

Here is a replicatable example:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-02"],
        "b": [None, None, None],
        "c": [4, 5, 6],
        "d": [None, None, None],
    }
)
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("a").str.strptime(pl.Date, "%Y-%m-%d", strict=False))
print(df)
ctx = pl.SQLContext(stuff=df)
new_df = ctx.execute(
    "select * from stuff where a = cast('2023-06-01' as date)",
    eager=True,
)
print(new_df)


## Returns...
shape: (3, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ f32  ┆ i64 ┆ f32  │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 4   ┆ null │
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 5   ┆ null │
│ 2023-06-02 ┆ null ┆ 6   ┆ null │
└────────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘
shape: (0, 4)
┌──────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ a    ┆ b   ┆ c   ┆ d   │
│ ---  ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ date ┆ f32 ┆ i64 ┆ f32 │
╞══════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
└──────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Just curious, if you like SQL, why not use duckdb?

Comment: Good question.  The team did not want to run the whole duckdb in Lambda.  Also, pyarrow was about 8x faster.  Polars so far is 3x faster.

Comment: However, this performance difference may be due to Duckdb's memory reservation.  We haven't explored that possibility yet.

Comment: That sounds like a very *unique* case to observe those performance discrepancies,

Comment: 450M rows of data taking about 7GB in compressed parquet.  The query grouped by 3 columns and had 5 sum(case...) aggregations while filtering on the same 3 grouped columns.  We used Hive style partitions in all cases and used the same amount of memory in all cases.

Comment: the use case is to support reporting queries from our web platform in order to avoid escalating Snowflake costs.

Comment: Comparing dates with strings was [explicity disallowed in Polars.](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/6498) Not sure if there are plans to allow this in SQLContext. It doesn't look like any work has been done yet on date functionality from what I can find: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7227

Comment: could you elaborate on "This runs, but does not return expected results."

Comment: Yes. Done.  It does not return any records

Comment: `DATE()` was added in `0.19.9` https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11541

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATE()` was [was added as an SQL function](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/11541) in Polars `0.19.9`

- [`.str.to_date()`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.to_date.html#polars-expr-str-to-date) can be used instead of `.str.strptime()`

```py
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": ["2023-06-01", "2023-06-01", "2023-06-02"],
        "b": [None, None, None],
        "c": [4, 5, 6],
        "d": [None, None, None],
    }
)

df = df.with_columns(pl.col("a").str.to_date())

with pl.SQLContext(stuff=df) as ctx:
    ctx.execute(
        "select * from stuff where a = date('2023-06-01')",
        eager=True
    )
```

```py
shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ f32  ┆ i64 ┆ f32  │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 4   ┆ null │
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 5   ┆ null │
└────────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Being able to use `.cast()` to go from `str` -> `date|datetime` [has been added with #12072](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/12072) which will be part of the next Polars release.

```py
with pl.SQLContext(stuff=df) as ctx:
    ctx.execute(
        "select * from stuff where a = cast('2023-06-01' as date)",
        eager=True
    )
```

```py
shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ f32  ┆ i64 ┆ f32  │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 4   ┆ null │
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 5   ┆ null │
└────────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘
```

Comment: suh-weet.  this is what I really needed and what others will need.  marking this as accepted

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two things working against you.

1. the parser won't implicitly cast a string to a date
2. [as of 2023-10-05 there isn't a function available to cast a string to a date.](https://docs.rs/polars-sql/latest/src/polars_sql/functions.rs.html)

Some work arounds:

1. Use the API instead of SQL

```
df.filter(pl.col('a')==pl.date(2023,6,1))
shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ f32  ┆ i64 ┆ f32  │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 4   ┆ null │
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 5   ┆ null │
└────────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘
```

2. Create a new table with the date you want as a column and then do an inner join. (I include this kind of as a joke, this isn't something I would do)

```
datedf=pl.DataFrame({'a':'2023-06-01'}).with_columns(a=pl.col('a').str.to_date())
ctx = pl.SQLContext(stuff=df, datedf=datedf)
ctx.execute("select * from stuff join datedf on stuff.a=datedf.a").collect()
shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ f32  ┆ i64 ┆ f32  │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 4   ┆ null │
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 5   ┆ null │
└────────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘
```

3. you can use duckdb

```
import duckdb
duckdb.sql("select * from df where a='2023-06-01'").pl()
shape: (2, 4)
┌────────────┬──────┬─────┬──────┐
│ a          ┆ b    ┆ c   ┆ d    │
│ ---        ┆ ---  ┆ --- ┆ ---  │
│ date       ┆ f32  ┆ i64 ┆ f32  │
╞════════════╪══════╪═════╪══════╡
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 4   ┆ null │
│ 2023-06-01 ┆ null ┆ 5   ┆ null │
└────────────┴──────┴─────┴──────┘
```

I know you said your team doesn't want to "run the whole duckdb" in lambda but I don't really know what that means. It isn't heavy and you would just add it to your requirements file. It's not like installing a postgres cluster. Additionally, it's interoperable with polars both in and out (except lazyframes). You don't have to register them, you just use them directly as above and with `.pl()` at the end its output is a polars dataframe.